# Generate random numbers with bivariate gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, random, gamma-distribution

How to generate random numbers with bivariate gamma distribution. The density is:

F<sub>(*X*, *Y*)</sub>(*x*, *y*) = α<sup>p+q</sup>x<sup>p-1</sup>(y-x)<sup>q-1</sup>*e*<sup>-αy</sup> / [Γ(*p*) Γ(*q*)], 𝕀<sub>0≤ x≤ y</sub>

With y>x>0, α>0, p>0 and q>0.

I did not find any package on R that does this and nothing in literature.

Comment: Bivariate MacKay distribution is implemented in the VGAM library, check bivgamma.mackay

Comment: It seems that this package only estimates the parameters of the bivariate gamma distribution using maximum likelihood estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward:

1. Generate X~ Gamma(p,alpha)  (alpha being the rate parameter in your formulation)
2. Generate W~ Gamma(q,alpha), independent of X
3. Calculate Y=X+W
4. (X,Y) have the required bivariate distribution.

in R (assuming p,q,alpha and n are already defined):

```
x <- rgamma(n,p,alpha)
y <- x + rgamma(n,q,alpha)
```

generates n values from the bivariate distribution with parameters p,q,alpha